# Action if all elements have the same property css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want do something if all elements with same css class have the same css
property value.

Here's my attempt which doesn't work:

```
$('.element-item').each(function() {
  if( $(".element-item").css('background') = '#ccc') {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Answer (score 1):

In javascript `==` is the operator to compare values. Using a single '=' assignment operator will result in a `ReferenceError` (due to invalid assignment) which stops processing of your "do-something" block of code.

```
$('.element-item').each(function() {
  if( $(".element-item").css('background') == '#ccc') {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you I think it was just a deep tiredness, shame on me

Comment: @kwiz no worries my friend

Answer (score 1):

You can check all selectors by below code:

```
$('.element-item').each(function() {
   if( $(this).css('background') == '#ccc') {
      // do something
   }
});
```

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access compound properties like that. If you are *really* interested in the color, and it's not just an example, you'll have to use `background-color`. Also, the value returned will be `rgb` so you are going to need a little math.

As I understand, you want your function to run *once* only if all elements in the collection pass the check, so you can't use an `each` loop because it will run for each element that matches the condition.

You can filter the elements for the property that you are interested in and check if the two collections contain the same number of items.

```js
checkItems(".element-item");
checkItems(".element-item2");

function checkItems(selector) {
  $items = $(selector);
  $ccc = $items.filter(function() {
    return ($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(204, 204, 204)');
  });

  if ($items.length == $ccc.length) {
    // Same number of elements, run the function
    console.log(selector + " passes the test");
  } else {
    console.log(selector + " doesn't pass the test");
  }
}
```

```css
.element-item,
.element-item2 {
  background: #ccc;
}

#black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element-item"></div>
<div class="element-item"></div>
<div class="element-item"></div>

<div class="element-item2"></div>
<div class="element-item2"></div>
<div class="element-item2" id="black"></div>
```